# How to enable both multiple selection and drag and drop of images displayed in a flowbox using Python and GTK 3

Tags: python-3.x, drag-and-drop, selection, gtk3

I am working on an application that displays and catalogs images and exports web pages. I am using Python 3, GTK 3. The images are displayed in a flowbox.  Two features that I want are to be able to select multiple images to be acted on by keystrokes, and also to be able to drag and drop images to rearrange them on them in the flowbox. I can implement either of these features, but not both at the same time. The selection works if I use frames to display the images, the drag/drop works if I use buttons to display the images. I have tried stacking both and have also tried to modify/add the events on the widgets, but fell down deep rabbit holes each time.

Ubuntu 16.04
Python Version: 3.5.2 (default, Sep 10 2016, 08:21:44) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
GTK version: 3.18.9

Below are two test pieces of code that show the behavior I am trying to combine.  dndfromscratch.py enables drag and drop.  selectdndfromscratch.py allows one or both images to be selected.

dndfromscratch.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# dndfromscratch.py
### http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drag_and_drop.html

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

STARRED_IMAGE = '/home/mark/photoPlay2/Star-24m.png'

DRAG_ACTION = Gdk.DragAction.COPY

class DragDropWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Drag and Drop Demo")
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)

        flowbox = Gtk.FlowBox()
        flowbox.set_valign(Gtk.Align.START)
        flowbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)
        flowbox.set_activate_on_single_click(False)

        button = Gtk.Button()
        star = Gtk.Image.new_from_file(STARRED_IMAGE)
        button.add(star)
        flowboxchild = Gtk.FlowBoxChild()
        self.flowboxchild = flowboxchild
        flowboxchild.add(button)
        flowboxchild.connect("key-press-event", self.on_key_press_event)

        button2 = Gtk.Button()
        star2 = Gtk.Image.new_from_file(STARRED_IMAGE)
        button2.add(star2)
        flowboxchild2 = Gtk.FlowBoxChild()
        self.flowboxchild2 = flowboxchild2
        flowboxchild2.add(button2)
        flowboxchild2.connect("key-press-event", self.on_key_press_event)

        flowbox.add(flowboxchild)
        flowbox.add(flowboxchild2)
        self.add(flowbox)

        button.drag_source_set(Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK, [], Gdk.DragAction.COPY)
        button.drag_source_add_image_targets()
        button.drag_source_add_text_targets()
        button.drag_source_add_uri_targets()
        button.connect("drag_begin", self.drag_begin_cb)
        button.connect("drag_data_get", self.drag_data_get_cb)
#        button.connect("drag_data_delete", self.drag_data_delete_cb)
#        button.connect("drag_end", self.drag_end_cb)

        self.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], DRAG_ACTION)
        self.drag_dest_add_image_targets()
        self.drag_dest_add_text_targets()
        self.drag_dest_add_uri_targets()
        self.connect("drag_motion", self.drag_motion_cb)
        self.connect("drag_drop", self.drag_drop_cb)
        self.connect("drag_data_received", self.drag_data_received_cb)

        button2.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], DRAG_ACTION)
        button2.drag_dest_add_image_targets()
        button2.drag_dest_add_text_targets()
        button2.drag_dest_add_uri_targets()
        button2.connect("drag_motion", self.drag_motion_cb)
        button2.connect("drag_drop", self.drag_drop_cb)
        button2.connect("drag_data_received", self.drag_data_received_cb)

        self.show_all()

    def on_key_press_event(self, widget, event):
        print (widget, event)
        print ('flowboxchild:', self.flowboxchild.is_selected())
        print ('flowboxchild2:', self.flowboxchild2.is_selected())
        return False

    def drag_begin_cb(self, widget, drag_context):
        print ('drag begin')
        print (self, widget, drag_context)
        return (drag_context)

    def drag_data_get_cb(self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
        print ('drag data get')
        print (self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time)

    def drag_motion_cb(self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
        print ('drag motion')
        print (self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time)
        return (drag_context)

    def drag_drop_cb(self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
        print ('drag drop')
        print (self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time)
        return (drag_context)

    def drag_data_received_cb(self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
        print ('drag data received')
        print (self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time)
        return (drag_context)

win = DragDropWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

selectdndfromscratch.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# selectdndfromscratch.py
### http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drag_and_drop.html

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

STARRED_IMAGE = '/home/mark/photoPlay2/Star-24m.png'

DRAG_ACTION = Gdk.DragAction.COPY

class DragDropWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Drag and Drop Demo")
        self.set_default_size(200, 200)

        flowbox = Gtk.FlowBox()
        flowbox.set_valign(Gtk.Align.START)
        flowbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)
        flowbox.set_activate_on_single_click(False)

        button = Gtk.Frame()
        star = Gtk.Image.new_from_file(STARRED_IMAGE)
        button.add(star)
        flowboxchild = Gtk.FlowBoxChild()
        self.flowboxchild = flowboxchild
        flowboxchild.add(button)
        flowboxchild.connect("key-press-event", self.on_key_press_event)

        button2 = Gtk.Frame()
        star2 = Gtk.Image.new_from_file(STARRED_IMAGE)
        button2.add(star2)
        flowboxchild2 = Gtk.FlowBoxChild()
        self.flowboxchild2 = flowboxchild2
        flowboxchild2.add(button2)
        flowboxchild2.connect("key-press-event", self.on_key_press_event)

        flowbox.add(flowboxchild)
        flowbox.add(flowboxchild2)
        self.add(flowbox)

        button.drag_source_set(Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK, [], Gdk.DragAction.COPY)
        button.drag_source_add_image_targets()
        button.drag_source_add_text_targets()
        button.drag_source_add_uri_targets()
        button.connect("drag_begin", self.drag_begin_cb)
        button.connect("drag_data_get", self.drag_data_get_cb)
#        button.connect("drag_data_delete", self.drag_data_delete_cb)
#        button.connect("drag_end", self.drag_end_cb)

        self.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], DRAG_ACTION)
        self.drag_dest_add_image_targets()
        self.drag_dest_add_text_targets()
        self.drag_dest_add_uri_targets()
        self.connect("drag_motion", self.drag_motion_cb)
        self.connect("drag_drop", self.drag_drop_cb)
        self.connect("drag_data_received", self.drag_data_received_cb)

        button2.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], DRAG_ACTION)
        button2.drag_dest_add_image_targets()
        button2.drag_dest_add_text_targets()
        button2.drag_dest_add_uri_targets()
        button2.connect("drag_motion", self.drag_motion_cb)
        button2.connect("drag_drop", self.drag_drop_cb)
        button2.connect("drag_data_received", self.drag_data_received_cb)

        self.show_all()

    def on_key_press_event(self, widget, event):
        print (widget, event)
        print ('flowboxchild:', self.flowboxchild.is_selected())
        print ('flowboxchild2:', self.flowboxchild2.is_selected())
        return False

    def drag_begin_cb(self, widget, drag_context):
        print ('drag begin')
        print (self, widget, drag_context)
        return (drag_context)

    def drag_data_get_cb(self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
        print ('drag data get')
        print (self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time)

    def drag_motion_cb(self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
        print ('drag motion')
        print (self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time)
        return (drag_context)

    def drag_drop_cb(self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
        print ('drag drop')
        print (self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time)
        return (drag_context)

    def drag_data_received_cb(self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
        print ('drag data received')
        print (self, widget, drag_context, data, info, time)
        return (drag_context)

win = DragDropWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: You can make it so that when holding `Ctrl` the images would be dragged, and when not holding `Ctrl` – selected.